# Dynamic Previous page link in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-linking

I want to create a "Previous Entries" link in PHP. This is not a simple entries list where you fetch a fixed amount of rows from MySQL database. The catch here is: The row entries may vary each time the link gets called.

What is happening actually is I am looking date wise. I am showing the latest date's entries on the front page. There may be multiple rows with same date. I have to show all the entries on the same page. When user clicks on Previous Entry Link, it will fetch the next most recent date and fetch entries with that date and show it on the page and when user clicks on Previous Entry link again, it should show the third most recent date's entries. In this way it should continue. The same thing I also want to do it for Newer Entries.

I am not getting the idea as to how to go ahead with it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My language is PHP and database is: MySQL

Comment: So the previous link wouldn't need to find a single mysql record, but rather the previous (by calendar) date that has any mysql entries, correct?

Comment: Actually it should find all the row entries from mysql record but all those records should correspond to the next recent date which is also a field in that table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using date as method of distinguishing your row, use an auto-ID (IDENTITY column). This way, there is no duplication of ID, and then you can just subtract 1 or add 1 to get previous/next entry.

Comment: I am using an auto number for distinguishing each entries,so there is no duplication of id actually. But, I want to show only those rows in previous link which is of the next most recent date

Answer (score 0):

Edited for clarity/possible language barrier.

If the currently selected date is `2013-03-28` then you need to find the closest previous date. There are tons of ways to do this (in order of efficiency):

- Use mysql's `DATE_DIFF` method and order by the difference, you'll find the records with the closest date or and can just query for the date itself and do a second query for all records for that date.
- Use php to loop through dates previous to the current, querying mysql for any records on that day (inefficient)
- Query for all unique dates in the db and cache that somewhere, and just lookup whichever date comes next.

Once you know that the previous date of records is `2012-11-01`, you can easily query for all records with such a date/timestamp.

Comment: I am not actually getting what you want to say. I am sorry for that. But based on what I got from your answer, I can say that my date field only stores date, day, month and year. It will not be like that there will be entries for all the days. .....continued....

Comment: ......continued....... Lets say there is an entry for today i.e. Thursday, 28 March, 2013 then the next most recent date may be Friday, 2 November, 2012. Now, there may be say 10 rows with the date Thursday, 28 March, 2013 and 15 rows with the date Friday, 2 November, 2012. Then, how will you show the 10 rows of 28 March, 2013 on the first page and when you click on Previous Entries it should show the 15 entries of 2 November, 2012. I don't know you have already answered my question or not, but this is just to be more clear.